# Copy the emmc content of Beaglebone running angstrom on SD card to make an emmc flasher image

Tags: beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

I have an emmc-flasher angstrom image on my BBB, I want to copy the content of the emmc image on an SD card and make it as an emmc-flasher so that I can flash the other BBB with the changes I made on the current BBB.
Tried following this method but didn't worked

http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents

any guesses or clues ?

Comment: Really Ångström? Not Debian?

Comment: Please clarify what you are exactly running on the board, including version/release.

Comment: Yes, its Angstrom emmc flasher image.

Comment: In case of Ångström the intended workflow is to produce images with desired content using the OpenEmbedded environment. Reverting from a manually modified image to a flasher was never intended, so will be hackish. On the other hand the recent Debian images come with a script to do that. If it's just one more board, you could always just boot from a large SD and do a simple copy of the whole eMMC block device.

Answer (score 1):

Some boards can't boot up from the SD card prepared according to [the instruction you are referring to](http://elinux.org/BeagleBone_Black_Extracting_eMMC_contents).
If this is the case then you can use alternative method:

1. Prepare an SD card using some generic image. For example [from here](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images) but you can use [the flasher image as well](https://debian.beagleboard.org/images/BBB-eMMC-flasher-debian-7.5-2014-05-14-2gb.img.xz).
2. Boot from the SD card (hold the Boot Button during power on).
3. ssh to your BeagleBone
4. you can save the image on your SD card or transfer it to a server

   - to save the image to your SD card first create a partition for it or mount an external USB drive (my favourite option) then create eMMC image: 
     `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 of=/mnt/usb/BeagleBoneEMMC.img bs=10M`
   - or scp the image straight to your backup server: `sudo dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 | ssh user@targetserver 'dd of=BeagleBoneEMMC.img'`

After that, you can use `dd` to prepare the SD cards.